# Rendering a custom object vf page as pdf in salesforce1 chatter

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, chatter, professional-edition

we use sfdc pe. We have a custom object where we render invoices as pdf and display it on browser in desktop edition.

However same functionality does not work in salesforce1.

I recently realized that, in salesforce1, "files" on chatter work very good & pdf docs are smoothly opened displayed in salesforce1 chatter.

my question is, is there any way to use file displaying feature of salesforce1 chatter to display my custom object pdf documents? Which code should I add to my vidualforce page to display rendered pdf documents on salesforce1 thru chatter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you're having is that until you save the VF page as a file, it can't be viewed using the PDF file viewer in your mobile browser. Prior to that point, you're essentially "printing" it as a PDF for saving, but are instead getting a "preview", which a regular browser is able to handle. If I'm not mistaken this is known issue within the SF1 app and isn't limited to the PE edition.